# Manually polling streams in future implementation

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, rust-tokio

I'm in the process of migrating to `futures` 0.3 and `tokio` 0.2, and there is one recurring pattern I can't manage to re-use. I'm not sure whether this pattern became obsolete or whether I'm doing something wrong wrt to `Pin`.

Usually I have one type that holds a socket and a few channel receivers. The `Future` implementation for such structs consists in polling the streams repeatedly until they return `Pending` (`NotReady` in the 0.1 ecosystem).

However, in futures 0.3, `Future::poll` and `Stream::poll_next` take `self` instead of `&mut self`, and this pattern does not work anymore:

```rust
use futures::{
    stream::Stream,
    task::{Context, Poll},
    Future,
};
use std::pin::Pin;
use tokio::sync::mpsc::{Receiver, Sender};

/// Dummy structure that represent some state we update when we
/// receive data or events.
struct State;

impl State {
    fn update(&mut self, _data: Vec<u8>) {
        println!("updated state");
    }
    fn handle_event(&mut self, _event: u32) {
        println!("handled event");
    }
}

/// The future I want to implement.
struct MyFuture {
    state: State,
    data: Receiver<Vec<u8>>,
    events: Receiver<Vec<u8>>,
}

impl MyFuture {
    fn poll_data(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<()> {
        use Poll::*;

        let MyFuture {
            ref mut data,
            ref mut state,
            ..
        } = self.get_mut();

        loop {
            // this breaks, because Pin::new consume the mutable
            // reference on the first iteration of the loop.
            match Pin::new(data).poll_next(cx) {
                Ready(Some(vec)) => state.update(vec),
                Ready(None) => return Ready(()),
                Pending => return Pending,
            }
        }
    }

    // unimplemented, but we basically have the same problem than with
    // `poll_data()`
    fn poll_events(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<()> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        use Poll::*;
        if let Ready(_) = self.poll_data(cx) {
            return Ready(());
        }

        // This does not work because self was consumed when
        // self.poll_data() was called.
        if let Ready(_) = self.poll_events(cx) {
            return Ready(());
        }
        return Pending;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix that code? If not, what pattern could I use to implement the same logic?

Comment: use `pinned.as_mut()` to avoid consuming the pinned value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Pin::as_mut` to avoid consuming the `Pin`.

```
impl MyFuture {
    fn poll_data(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<()> {
        use Poll::*;

        let MyFuture {
            ref mut data,
            ref mut state,
            ..
        } = self.get_mut();

        let mut data = Pin::new(data); // Move pin here
        loop {
            match data.as_mut().poll_next(cx) {   // Use in loop by calling `as_mut()`
                Ready(Some(vec)) => state.update(vec),
                Ready(None) => return Ready(()),
                Pending => return Pending,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in Future impl:

```
impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        use Poll::*;
        // `as_mut()` here to avoid consuming
        if let Ready(_) = self.as_mut().poll_data(cx) { 
            return Ready(());
        }

        // can consume here as this is the last invocation
        if let Ready(_) = self.poll_events(cx) {
            return Ready(());
        }
        return Pending;
    }
}
```

#### EDIT:

**Tip**: Try to use `Pin` only when necessary. In your case, you don't really need Pinned pointer in `poll_data` function. `&mut self` is just fine, which reduces `Pin` usage a little:

```
impl MyFuture {
    fn poll_data(&mut self, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<()> {
        use Poll::*;

        loop {
            match Pin::new(&mut self.data).poll_next(cx) {
                Ready(Some(vec)) => self.state.update(vec),
                Ready(None) => return Ready(()),
                Pending => return Pending,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Future impl:

```
impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Output = ();

    fn poll(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        use Poll::*;
        if let Ready(_) = self.poll_data(cx) {
            return Ready(());
        }

        if let Ready(_) = self.poll_events(cx) {
            return Ready(());
        }
        return Pending;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alleluia! Now that I see it, it seems obvious, but I had tried many combinations with `as_mut()` and `get_mut()` before without managing to get it working.